pg_restore database as a different user to the owner in PostgreSQL 16
I am looking to use pg_restore to import a PostgreSQL 16 database, however I am hitting issues with ownership of the database and tables.
I would like the database to be owned by root (which it is) and the tables to be owned by the ibrox user.
CREATE DATABASE template_crmpicco_1872 TEMPLATE template0 ENCODING 'UTF8'
GRANT ALL ON DATABASE template_crmpicco_1872 TO ibrox

When I try to restore the database with the ibrox user, I get this error:
Command /usr/bin/pg_restore --disable-triggers -d template_crmpicco_1872 -h crmpiccopg.anh73jdk19.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -n public -U ibrox -O -x /tmp/tmpimy39zj2/template_crmpicco_1872

pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  permission denied for schema public

How can I achieve this with PostgreSQL 16?

Before you restore the data, give the user the CREATE privilege on the public schema:
GRANT CREATE ON SCHEMA public TO ibrox;

You have to run that statement after creating the database, and you have to connect to the new database to run the statement.
Note that the behavior changed in PostgreSQL v15. Before that, everybody could create objects in the public schema. That constituted a security headache, hence the behavior change.

Thanks for your comment. Before I restore the data or before I create the database?

Either way, I seem to get the same error as before pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  permission denied for schema public

I thought that was obvious.

Sorry, the problem persists either way unfortunately.

Sorry, but then you are either connected to a different database, or you ran the GRANT in the wrong database or on the wrong server, or you didn't run pg_restore with that database user ibrox.
